# numberOfRowsInSection initially called with non-Zero value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When the following datasource gets called for the first time

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.firstFetchedResultController.sections.count + self.secondFetchedResultController.sections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger rowsCount = 0;
    NSLog(@"Section : %ld", (long)section);

    //First result controller
    if (section < [self.secondFetchedResultController.sections count]) {
        id  sectionInfo = [self.firstFetchedResultController sections][section];
        rowsCount = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    } else {    //Second result controller
        id  sectionInfo = [self.secondFetchedResultController sections][section];
        rowsCount = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }

    return rowsCount;
}
```

the section value which gets printed initially is 3. And when it enters into the numberOfRows now the app crashes since the loop will take the process to else block and my secondFetchedResultController doesn't have 3rd section in it.

FYI: I am using two fetchedResultsController in the current ViewController. And I am facing crash since the first/secondViewController doesn't have value for section 3 in this case.

Comment: Why does it matter what order it's in? The table view can ask for any section at any time in any order.

Comment: can you show me your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method implementation? I wonder why your code meets a crash.

Comment: Check that sectionInfo != nil before calling the numberOfObjects method on it.

Comment: If you don't have for section 3, why did you pass wrong number of sections in that case?

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you, now I understood that the order may vary anytime & the issue isn't due to it.

Comment: @KyokookHwang, I have updated my question with numberOfSectionsInTableView method, please check it out.

Comment: @Bamsworld, Thank you I tried, but app gets crashed on `id  sectionInfo = [self.firstFetchedResultController sections][section];' this line itself.

Comment: @HossamGhareeb, I didn't pass 3, I have updated my question, please review it, I think now you can get why number of sections gets 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subtract the count of the first resultController to the section in order to have an index starting from 0 :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSInteger rowsCount = 0;
    NSLog(@"Section : %ld", (long)section);

    // Let's save the count to a variable in order to have an answer more readable
    NSInteger firstSectionCount = [self.secondFetchedResultController.sections count];

    //First result controller
    if (section < firstSectionCount) {
        id  sectionInfo = [self.firstFetchedResultController sections][section];
        rowsCount = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    } else {    //Second result controller
        // HERE, we subtract firstSectionCount to section.
        id  sectionInfo = [self.secondFetchedResultController sections][section - firstSectionCount];
        rowsCount = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }

    return rowsCount;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but the need for such processing reveals a design flaw.  Wouldn't life be so much easier if those *fetched result controllers* were merged as soon as possible?

Comment: I agree that merge the results from Core-Data would simplify this code and made this part more readable (Since this subtraction will always occurs in `cellForRow`, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, ...). Maybe the OP will realize it by reading the comments, understand the issue in this design, and remember it the next time he faces this kind of issue. That's all I hope for him :)

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo The above logic fixed my issue, Thank you. I have never used the merge concept which you & trojanfoe was speaking about. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

This will crash if self.firstFetchedResultController have 0 Sections and self.secondFetchedResultController more than 0 sections